# Will takeUntil() work with Observable<void>?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

The documentation says that `takeUntil` continues to emit values until the passed observable emits *a value*. It doesn't say until *subscribe* is called.

I'm wondering if the following is safe to do?

```
const x = new Subject<void>();

async.pipe(takeUntil(x)).subscribe(()=>.....);

x.next(); // <-- no value
```

The alternative would be to emit some kind of value in `x.next(true)`.

Comment: Yes, this is safe to do. 'x.next()' will finish the subscription.

Comment: Llorenç Pujol Ferriol can you answer the question with an answer instead of a comment :) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes calling `x.next()` is safe. By inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.2/src/internal/operators/takeUntil.ts#L81) it can be seen that `takeUntil` does not use the value emitted from Observable `x` and simply calls `complete()` on the source Observable.